# How do I modify the default name of react-redux connect function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-redux, onsen-ui

I'm using `onsen-ui` to style a `meteor` app with `React` for the frontend. As I understand it, `onsen-ui` manages navigation by `pushing` pages to a stack, where each page has a unique identifier.

Here is how my pages are loaded in `App.js`

```
loadPage = (page) => {
    const currentPage = this.navigator.pages.slice(-1)[0]

    if(currentPage.key != page.name){
        this.navigator.pushPage(
            {
                component: page,
                props: { key: page.name }
            },
            {
                animation: 'fade',
                animationOptions: {duration: 0.3, timing: 'ease-in'}
            },
        );
    }
}
```

So far everything works fine. But I have now included `redux` in my project, so I have some components which are connected to the store by `react-redux`'s `connect()` function.

The problem is that for every component that `connect` wraps, the name property becomes `Connect`, so `onsen-ui` is having to deal with multiple pages with the same name in its stack.

As an example, let's say I have a component defined below

```
const ComponentName = props => {
    return (
        <p>Test component</p>
    )
}

export default connect()(ComponentName)
```

ordinarily, `ComponentName.name` returns `ComponentName` but once its wrapped with `connect`, `ComponentName.name` returns `Connect`

Is it at all possible to modify the name value for the wrapped component?

Every suggestion is welcome.

## Edit: Following Vlatko's lead, this is how I eventually solved the problem.

```
export const getPageKey = (page) => {
    // returns a page key
    let key;
    if (page.name === 'Connect') {
        key = page.displayName
        // key = page.WrappedComponent.name
        // react-redux connect returns a name Connect
        // .displayName returns a name of form Connect(ComponentName)
        return key.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
    }
    else {
        key = page.name
        return key
    }
}
```

So for every component I just get the key with `getPageKey(ComponentName)`

## Edit 2. This approach doesn't work in production.

In production mode, I get single letters for `page.displayName` and those letters are hardly unique, which means I'm back where I started.

I need to find another approach. I'll update whatever I find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you are exporting your component through a higher order function (Connect), which is basically a closure in JavaScript.

The name of the HOC that you are using is Connect, and this is returned.

However, it is possible to get the name of the component passed into the connect HOC.

```
ComponentName.name // Connect
ComponentName.displayName // Connect(ComponentName)
ComponentName.WrappedComponent.name // ComponentName
```

Comment: It would be best if you edit the original post and add your update there below the question, so it is more visible and readable.

Comment: I just did that

Comment: Great ! I hope it will help others with the similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not familiar with `onsen-ui`, and it looks like Vlatko has you covered, but couldn’t you also give the new connected component a name? For example:

```
const ComponentName = props => {
    return (
        <p>Test component</p>
    )
}

const ConnectedComponentName = connect()(ComponentName)

export default ConnectedComponentName;
```

Then hopefully you would be able to access the unique `ConnectedComponentName`

Comment: This won't work. Once your export it the name changes to `Connect`